# Good way to condense search results?

Tags: mobile, android, mobile-application, search-results

In my app, after a user performs a query, the server sends back an array of results. Each item in the result is actually information about a particular organization - their name, their address, their coordinates, etc.  Specifically, each item in the result looks like this:

```
{
    "website": "...",
    "address": [
        {
            "line1": "",
            "line2": "",
            "zip": ,
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "geo": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    100.122,
                    199.123
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "contact": [
        {
            "country_code": "",
            "phone_number": ""
        }
    ],
    "causes": [
        "",
        ""
    ],
    "name": "",
    "about": "",
    "_id": ""
}
```

What would be a good layout to **display the most important information** about each organization? Examples would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a simple card based design where each card will represent each company.

A sample layout for your use case:

[image]

The **more** button indicates that the user can click to see more details about the corresponding company in another view. For the **About** details, you can show some amount of information and use ellipsis i.e something like this.

*"Some text about the company..."*

This would be good to let the user know that there is some more information present.

Few suggestions. Use the space properly and provide proper focus points. Highlight the information with proper colors so that the user can quickly grab what is needed.

You can also look at the search results for Google or Linkedin search results(*Search for a company*) to get more idea on how you can proceed with you layout.

Hope I could help :)

Comment: This is a really nice design. I think moving the "City, State" below "Company Name" would be good just in case "Company Name" is very long.

Comment: Yes. That would also be a good idea.